# Haskell Tree delete a node / calculate all possible paths

Tags: haskell, tree

I have these  structures:

```
data Tree = Leaf Points | Branch Points [Tree]
deriving(Eq,Show)

data Design = Design Tree Tree Int
deriving(Eq,Show)
```

data type `Tree` is a part of data type `Design` and `Design` holds two `Trees`:

```
 type Points = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]

 design = Design mtree btree 180
```

I have to find all the possible paths:

```
numberPaths :: Design -> Int
```

and change the third `Integer` from `Points` and also 180 from `design`:

```
type Points = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]
design = Design mtree btree 180

changeInt :: Design -> Design
```

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: I have to find all the possible paths in design tree and change one Int in Points and then 180 in design again.

Comment: You've told us what you have to do, but you still haven't told us what part you are having trouble with and want help on.

Answer (score 0):

### Count paths

To find the number of paths in a tree, we recursively descend down the tree to count the number of subpaths for each node and then sum them up. So aside from having `numberPaths` as the interface, we also need another auxiliary function whose type signature is `Tree -> Int`. Let's call it `descend`.

```
descend :: Tree -> Int
```

We count `Leaf` as 1, and `Branch` as the sum of number of paths of its subtrees. So the `descend` becomes:

```
descend :: Tree -> Int 
descend (Leaf _)            = 1 
descend (Branch _ subtress) = foldr (\tree sum -> sum + descend tree) 0 subtrees
```

The function `numberPaths` only need to call `descend` to count its two trees.

```
numberPaths :: Design -> Int 
numberPaths (Design a b _) = descend a + descend b
```

### Chang Int

The type signature of `changeInt` indicates that no `Int` value is introduced to change `Design` type. This, I think, does not make sense so I have taken the liberty of changing it into `Int -> Design -> Design`.

The implementation of `changeInt` follows a similar pattern. To change the tree we recursively walk down each level of the tree. We also introduce an auxiliary function `changePoints`.

```
changeTree :: Int -> Tree -> Tree
changeTree n (Leaf points)            = Leaf $ changePoints n points
changeTree n (Branch points subtrees) = Branch points' subtrees'
    where points'   = changePoints n points 
          subtrees' = map (changeTree n) subtrees

changePoints :: Int -> Points -> Points 
changePoints n points = map (\(x, y, _, z) -> (x, y, n, z)) points
```

The `changeInt` then only needs to call `changeTree` to finish the job.

```
changeInt :: Int -> Design -> Design 
changeInt n (Design mtree btree _) = Design mtree' btree' n
    where mtree' = changeTree n mtree 
          btree' = changeTree n btree
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! What I mean:                                                                
data Tree = Leaf Points | Branch Points [Tree]                                    
has    type Points = [(Int,Int,Int,Int)] and i want to change the last Integer there.                                                                                                  
Also data Design = Design Tree Tree Int     has   design = Design mtree btree 180              and i want  to change that 180.